# unity，how to use generic by using js?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

When I write like this
`List.<Dictionary.<String, System.Object>>`,
the ide tells me
`Assets/Scripts/yhj/Model/PrintItem.js(23,71): BCE0044: expecting >, found '>>`.
How can I resolve it?

Comment: You probably mean `UnityScript`. While it is called `Javascript` sometimes in the Unity documentation, it is so far from the original language that calling it that just creates more confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you make a list of dictionaries? Can't you just use the dictionary as the list with the key, value input instead of this? If you wanted to use it like this I would either define an object to be the `<String, System.Object>` and inserting that as the value and just leave the key as the number.

Or making a list of objects where the object is the `<String, System.Object>`

Comment: Because my data is json from server.And its structure should be this,and when i try to translate to my model,I get the problem.Luckily now i have resolved my question. I use the list  like `List.<System.Object>` first,and then do `list[i] as Dictionary<String, System.Object>`. Thank you for your help,you give me the advice

Comment: Glad you solved it! If my question helped with doing that you should mark it as the answer :) So people having the same problem can use it in the future

Answer (score 0):

@ILiveForVR makes me think about this.thanks.
I solved it, but I'm not sure if the solution is best.
I do it like this:

    `var list = List.<System.Object>;
    for(var i=0;i<list.Count;i++){
       var data = list[i] as Dictionary<String, System.Object>;
    }`